# ionic retrive data from database with http request

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm tring to learn how to use Ionic framework,

I've made a controller to get some data from a database using play 2.0 as web server.
This is my factory code :

```
    .factory('Projects', function($http) {
    var projects =  [];
    return {
        getProjects: function() {



            $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';       
            return $http({
                            method: 'POST', 
                            url: 'http://localhost:8101/getProjects', 
                            dataType: 'json',
                            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }

            }).success(function(data, status) {

                projects= data;
                return projects

            }).error(function(arg) {
            alert("error ");
        });
        }
    }
})
```

and my controller :

```
.controller('RootsCtrl', function($scope, Projects, $http) {

    $scope.projects= Projects.getProjects();


})
```

and here is my view :

```
<ion-view view-title="Projects">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="project in projects" type="item-text-wrap" >
        <h2>{{project.try}}</h2>          
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The web server only return some fake data by now.

I can't understand why, in my view,  the value for project.try isn't show, but the row is present.
So if I have two values, in my html I can see two row, but without their "name".
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you each item content has an item try ? {{project.try}}
Show us a "project" item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factories are singletons and return an object that contains the members of the service.

```
.factory('Project', function($http, $log) {
  return {
    getProjects: getProjects
  };

  function getProject(){
    var config = {
      method: 'POST', 
      url: 'http://localhost:8101/getProjects', 
      headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    }
    return $http(config).then(success).catch(failure);
  }

  function success(resp){
    return resp.data;
  }

  function failure(error){
    return error;
  }
});
```

$http returns a promise.

```
//Controller

.controller('RootsController', function(Project){
  var vm = this;

  fetchProject();

  function fetchProject(){
    Project.getProject().then(success, failure);
  }

  function success(data){
    vm.projects = data;
  }

  function failure(err){
    // Error Handling
  }
});
```

In your view:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat = "project in vm.projects">
  {{project}}
</ion-item>
```

Also in your states:

```
controller: 'RootsController as vm' because Ionic has issues with controllerAs syntax.
```

Also you are not posting any data? And you can see just rows and not names because the `project` object exists but might not contain a key called `try`

Comment: This work perfectly, thanks. Now I understand a little more of Ionic.